# SoapUI response parsing for property transfer

Tags: xml-parsing, xquery, soapui

I have a soap response containing transaction ID (TranId).

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m0="http://schemas.blablabla.com/two/1.0/filter.xsd" xmlns:m="http://schemas.blablabla.com/two/1.0/filter.wsdl">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <m:AcctDebitRp xmlns:m="http://schemas.blablabla.com/two/1.0/filter.xsd">
         <Response Response="1" TranId="**30538801**" Ver="14.3" Product="filter">
            <m0:ApprovalCode>557885</m0:ApprovalCode>
         </Response>
      </m:AcctDebitRp>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I retrieve transaction id value ?

I am using the below code in SoapUI property transfer step to retrieve the value of ApprovalCode:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://schemas.blablabla.com/two/1.0/filter.xsd';
//ns1:ApprovalCode
```

Is it possible to get the TranId value using XQuery in property transfer step or using groovy script step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for attributes using an `@attributename` child step. In the example you provided, the `<Response/>` element has no namespace attached, thus the query for the attribute is a simple

```
//*:Response/@TranId
```

If you only want the attribute *value*, consider applying the `data(...)` function:

```
data(//*:Response/@TranId)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I had inserted string data(//Response/@TranId) but transfered value is [null]. Could you me a cue what i`m doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the snippet you posted above the full SOAP result, or only a snippet? It seems there are more namespaces involved. if you add more relevant information, please consider editing your question instead of using comments (have a look at the [FAQ]).

Comment: trying to add an imagehttp://i11.pixs.ru/storage/7/7/6/soapquestJ_6037373_21430776.jpg

Comment: Jens Erat thank for your comments. The snippet i`ve posted above is the full SOAP result

Comment: SoapUI requires the namespace as well.